# How to map data to a new array with specific fields and values and add a single object per day based on a range of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have difficulties finding a way to map an array of objects, to a new array that will need to have objects defined by specific fields and values plus I also need to add objects by a single day, will explain details further down and I cannot use for loops of any kind due code style restriction I have in my project

The data I need to map to a new array

```
[
    {
      id: 'C12-TBX4',
      studyId: 'TBX4',
      siteId: 'USA-1',
      statusType: 'INCOMPLETE',
      statusFrom: '2020-12-01',
      statusTo: '2020-12-05'
    },
    {
      id: 'C13-TBX4',
      studyId: 'TBX4',
      siteId: 'USA-1',
      statusType: 'INCOMPLETE',
      statusFrom: '2020-12-03',
      statusTo: '2020-12-07'
    },
    {
      id: 'C14-TBX4',
      studyId: 'TBX4',
      siteId: 'USA-1',
      statusType: 'INCOMPLETE',
      statusFrom: '2020-12-05',
      statusTo: '2020-12-08'
    },
    {
      id: 'C15-TBX4',
      studyId: 'TBX4',
      siteId: null,
      statusType: 'REJECTED',
      statusFrom: '2020-12-05',
      statusTo: '2020-12-08'
    },
    {
      id: 'C16-TBX4',
      studyId: 'TBX4',
      siteId: null,
      statusType: 'REJECTED',
      statusFrom: '2020-12-05',
      statusTo: '2020-12-09'
    },
    {
      id: 'C17-TBX4',
      studyId: 'TBX4',
      siteId: 'USA-1',
      statusType: 'DROPOUT',
      eligible: true,
      statusFrom: '2020-12-05',
      statusTo: '2020-12-09'
    },
    {
      id: 'C17-TBX4',
      studyId: 'TBX4',
      siteId: 'USA-1',
      statusType: 'DROPOUT',
      eligible: false,
      statusFrom: '2020-12-05',
      statusTo: '2020-12-10'
    }
  ]
```

The above array needs to be compared and re-mapped using the following dates

```
 [
    2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-12-03T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-12-04T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-12-06T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z
  ]
```

The dates are in a range from the minimum to the maximum date of the data object.

The data object contains an interval as  `statusFrom` and `statusTo`; I need to have a new array of objects where we will have a single day from the dates object.

The array also will include a new field called `total` which is the total of `id` in a single study with the same `statusType` on the same day.

To give an example of the result I need to have

```
[
    // INCOMPLETE
    {
        "studyId": "TBX4",
        "siteId": "USA-1",
        "day": "2020-12-01",
        "statusType": "INCOMPLETE",
        "total": 1 // Only "id": "C12-TBX4",
    },
    {
        "studyId": "TBX4",
        "siteId": "USA-1",
        "day": "2020-12-02",
        "statusType": "INCOMPLETE",
        "total": 1 // Only "id": "C12-TBX4",
    },
    {
        "studyId": "TBX4",
        "siteId": "USA-1",
        "day": "2020-12-03",
        "statusType": "INCOMPLETE",
        "total": 2 // we have C13-TBX4 + C12-TBX4, dates are overlapping
    },
    {
        "studyId": "TBX4",
        "siteId": "USA-1",
        "day": "2020-12-03",
        "statusType": "INCOMPLETE",
        "total": 2 // we have C13-TBX4 + C12-TBX4, dates are overlapping
    },
    {
        "studyId": "TBX4",
        "siteId": "USA-1",
        "day": "2020-12-04",
        "statusType": "INCOMPLETE",
        "total": 2 // we have C13-TBX4 + C12-TBX4, dates are overlapping
    },
    {
        "studyId": "TBX4",
        "siteId": "USA-1",
        "day": "2020-12-05", // we include only status from and exclude status to
        "statusType": "INCOMPLETE",
        "total": 2 // we have C13-TBX4 + C14-TBX4, dates are overlapping -- C12-TBX4 is excluded
    },
    {
        "studyId": "TBX4",
        "siteId": "USA-1",
        "day": "2020-12-06",
        "statusType": "INCOMPLETE",
        "total": 2 // we have C13-TBX4 + C14-TBX4, dates are overlapping
    },
    {
        "studyId": "TBX4",
        "siteId": "USA-1",
        "day": "2020-12-07",
        "statusType": "INCOMPLETE",
        "total": 1 // we have C14-TBX4
    },
]
```

The above is just the example for the `statusType: INCOMPLETE` but the same logic needs to be done for the other statuses.

As you see the goal is to map a new array based on single dates in a range of dates and add the total of how many ids are in that status on that day by a single day.

I do not include any snippets as honestly have no idea where to start and how to do it

Comment: What sort of object is in the second array?  Are they dates or string descriptions of dates?

Comment: The second array is a new array of objects where the day is the day from the dates object. The dates are dates that are added by using the new Date() in the app.
The new array is a collection of objects per single day on a specific range of dates.For example we have statusFrom and statusTo and we consider from ` 2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z` so the first id will be included in new objects until statuTo. 
We will have as from my example in the question total 1 then again 1 than 2 because the new id is overlapping with the dates in satusFrom. They have the same status type, study id and site id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly, we're given studies that contain a range of days, and we're given a list of specific dates that the studies' ranges encompass. We want to produce study objects that indicate the specific day each contains, and do a little totaling based on matching days and types.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "C12-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05"
  },
  {
    id: "C13-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-03",
    statusTo: "2020-12-07"
  },
  {
    id: "C14-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05",
    statusTo: "2020-12-08"
  },
  {
    id: "C16-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: null,
    statusType: "REJECTED",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05",
    statusTo: "2020-12-09"
  },
  {
    id: "C17-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: null,
    statusType: "REJECTED",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05",
    statusTo: "2020-12-09"
  },
  {
    id: "C18-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "DROPOUT",
    eligible: true,
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05",
    statusTo: "2020-12-09"
  },
  {
    id: "C19-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "DROPOUT",
    eligible: false,
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05",
    statusTo: "2020-12-10"
  }
];

const rangeOfDates = [
  new Date("2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2020-12-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2020-12-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2020-12-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z")
];

// prepare input objects for search by date
let studies = data.map((s) => {
  let r = Object.assign({}, s);
  // getTime() gives scalar ms since the epoch, for simpler comparisons
  r.statusFrom = new Date(r.statusFrom).getTime();
  r.statusTo = r.statusTo ? new Date(r.statusTo).getTime() : 8640000000000000;
  return r;
});

// same for the times
let times = rangeOfDates.map((d) => {
  let time = d.getTime();
  let day = d.toISOString().split("T")[0]; // the day part of the string
  return { time, day };
});

let resultIndex = {};

times.forEach((t) => {
  // get the matching studies, recall that t is an epoch time and a day string
  let matchingStudies = studies.filter(s => {
    return s.statusFrom <= t.time && t.time < s.statusTo;
  });
  let idIndex = {};
  // particularize the matching studies with the matching day, and requiring a unique studyId-day
  matchingStudies.forEach(ms => {
    let r = {
      day: t.day,
      studyId: ms.studyId,
      siteId: ms.siteId,
      statusType: ms.statusType,
      total: 0
    };
    // require uniqueness of studyId-day, second input prevails
    let key = `${r.day}${r.studyId}`;
    idIndex[key] = r;
  });
  matchingStudies = Object.values(idIndex);

  // summarize totals by statusType-day
  matchingStudies.forEach(ms => {
    let key = `${ms.day}${ms.statusType}`;
    if (!resultIndex[key]) resultIndex[key] = ms;
    resultIndex[key].total++;
  })
});

let result = Object.values(resultIndex);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That looks great but maybe there is an error I created this sandbox using your answer
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-frost-9o12yw?file=/src/index.js
If you will see the console on the 3rd object we have duplicated the same date and same values. That probably should be one date one object. I believe those duplicates are incorrect. 
Can you check my sandbox, please

Comment: @Jakub - I think I understand now that the aim is to *combine* the objects based on same type and day.  I've added a snippet to the bottom that accomplishes that.  It does less work finding the results, then takes a second pass through to combine based on the same day and type.  You can run it just by pressing "run code snippet", no need for 3rd party sandbox.

Comment: Cool that looks good I'll do some tests but seem right :)

Comment: Now that we (probably) have it, I put the code on a diet and trimmed off some extra looping that was useful while coming to an understanding.  Pls see edit

Comment: That works great :) I have one question due to a detail I just discovered. 
What happens if the statusTo is null?
I'm asking because some data can come with statusTo Null because that means the status didn't change so they should be counted always in the range.

Comment: Glad it works. If statusTo === null means always include, just replace it with the largest possible getTime. I’ll edit…

Comment: Great that helped but I have another issue I received the right Dates to test and seems the const times are not working anymore with the following dates can you just tell me what edit I need 

[
        2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-03T00:00:00.000Z,
        2020-12-04T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-06T00:00:00.000Z,
        2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z,
        2020-12-10T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-11T00:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-12T00:00:00.000Z,]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246197/discussion-between-jakub-and-danh).